# What is this shape called (and made in Illustrator)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I really want to know how this shape is called and made in Illustrator. I know how to round corners of a rectangle but I'm not able to create such an element.[image]

Comment: aside from the black/gray boxes, you could add a layer with an image, (i.e., like the multi-colored stripes), then, add another layer above it and enter the 'M' with a font of your choice. Then convert the 'M' to an outline and make it a clipping path.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the white box, not the "M"

Comment: If what you're asking is: "What's that shape called"? In jewelry, they call it a cushion cut.

Comment: Inkscape has a Polygon tool, with a rounding option, and the ability to select a 4 sided polygon. [See example](https://imgur.com/a/BF00TNo). You could simply copy and paste it from Inskcape into Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Kindly check the attached picture, the entire process is written.[image]

Comment: Hey Suraiya,

Thank you very much but its not a Rectangle. See the left and right edges are also a little bit rounded and thats my problem because I dont know how to do it

Comment: kindly check the new picture. is tht Okay? i used pen tool.

Comment: Thats it, many thanks!